# dislike_count with pafy and youtube_dl

Tags: heroku, youtube, youtube-dl, pafy

I have a code for a discord bot that plays music in voice channels
and since youtube removed the dislike counter on video i get an error

```
nextcord.errors.ApplicationInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'dislike_count'
```

I tried to change the backend_youtube_dl.py file and it worked, but the thing is I am using Heroku to run the code and I can't change the file there

the code is quite large but this is the part causing the problem

```py
async def play_song(self, interaction, link):
    vid = pafy.new(link)
    url = vid.getbestaudio().url
    interaction.guild.voice_client.play(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(url)), after=lambda e: self.bot.loop.create_task(self.check_queue(interaction)))
```

Is there any other way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install git+https://github.com/mps-youtube/pafy.git
```

Installs the latest Jul 17, 2021 version which doesn't have the issue you are mentioning, while using `pip install pafy` installs the Nov 22, 2019 version which has the issue you are mentioning.